# Cannot submit change of address to subdomain in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect

I am pointing several domains to one URL, a URL which happens to include a subdomain.  ALL of the domains are using 301 redirects to point to this new address.

One of the older domains (which used to be a site) is a 'property' in Webmaster Tools, as is the new site (the one with the subdomain.)

When registering a 'Change of Address' for the old site with WebmasterTools, it suggests the following method -

- Set up your content on your new domain. **(done)**
- Redirect content from your old site using 301 redirects. **(done)**
- Add and verify your new site to Webmaster Tools. **(done)**

Then, directly below that, to proceed, it says

`Tell us the URL of your new domain:
Your account doesn't contain any sites we can use for a change of address. Add and verify the new site, then try again.`

I have already submitted and verified the new site.  The only reason I can fathom I am getting this error is because the new site includes a subdomain.

Although I don't foresee getting punished for this, as I am correctly 301 redirecting traffic anyway, I'm curious as to why the Change of Address submission isn't working appropriately for me.  Has anyone else had experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically because it's a subdomain.  Not sure why they choose this, but again, it doesn't necessarily hurt anything, it may just slow the process down.

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/webmasters/webmasters/iZ87oMwCsT4

There's also nothing really pertaining to this on this forum, so I believe it is educational to leave it.